# How do you convert a string to a node in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I would like to convert a string into a node. I have a method that is defined to take a node, but the value I have is a string (it is hard coded). How do I turn that string into a node?

So, given an XQuery method:

```
define function foo($bar as node()*) as node() {
  (: unimportant details :)
}
```

I have a string that I want to pass to the foo method. How do I convert the string to a node so that the method will accept the string.

Comment: Does the string contain some escaped XML that you want to parse into a node, or do you just want to turn the string into a text node so that you can pass it to this particular function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**MarkLogic solutions:**

The best way to convert a string into a node is to use:

```
xdmp:unquote($string).
```

Conversely if you want to convert a node into a string you would use:

```
xdmp:quote($node).
```

**Language agnostic solutions:**

Node to string is:

```
fn:string($node)
```

Comment: xdmp:unquote and quote aren't part of the XQuery language spec, it is part of a set of MarkLogic extension libraries. Loading xml from string literals into a node depends on the XQuery engine being used. http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1660

Comment: Also, you're node to string code probably doesn't do what the poster wants - it will only return the concatenated string value of all nodes below $node, but not the actual XML syntax (<foo/>)

Comment: I hate to accept my own answer, but this is what I was looking for and solved the problem I was having. Does the question need to be restated?

Comment: It's a reasonable way to ask.  You might also have asked how to parse (or de-serialize) a string into XML.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create a **text** node out of the string, just use a **text** node constructor:

```
text { "your string goes here" }
```

or if you prefer to create an **element** with the string content, you can construct an **element** something like this:

```
element (some-element) { "your string goes here" }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are talking about strings that contain XML markup, there are standardized solutions (from XPath/XQuery Functions 3.0) as well:

- string to node: [fn:parse-xml()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml)
- node to string: [fn:serialize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question depends on what engine is being used. For instance, users of **Saxon**, use the `saxon:parse` method.

The fact is the **XQuery** spec doesn't have a built in for this.

Generally speaking you would only really need to use this if you needed to pull some embedded **XML** from a **CDATA** section. Otherwise you can read files in from the filesystem, or declare **XML** directly inline.

For the most you would use the declarative form, instead of a hardcoded string e.g. (using Stylus studio)

```
declare namespace my = "http://tempuri.org";

declare function my:foo($bar as node()*) as node() {
    <unimportant></unimportant>
} ;

let $bar := <node><child></child></node>

return my:foo(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use `fn:parse-xml(xs:string)` to convert your current valid XML string into a document.